# Mocking a Python class that is instantiated in method under test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a system under test (Class `Printer` below), which uses another class (Class `ContentContainer` below). In one method (Method `retrieve_and_show_content` below), this class is instantiated. In the test for this method (Method `test_printer_03` below), I want to instantiate a mock instead of the real class. However, it doesn't work like this.

I read [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch) that I should change the object that a *name* points to with another one. It seems like the name of the object that I want to replace is simply `ContentContainer`, while the name of the object that I am actually replacing is `TestMockClass.ContentContainer`. Is this observation correct? If so, how do I change this? If I simply remove the prefix `TestMockClass` in the patch statement, I get a `TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: 'ContentContainer'`.

```
#TestMockClass.py
import unittest
from mock import Mock, patch

class Printer():
    def __init__(self, name, cc):
        self.name = name
        self.cc = cc
    def show_content(self):
        text = '{0} says: {1}'.format(self.name, self.cc.content())
        return text
    def retrieve_and_show_content(self):
        cc_tmp = ContentContainer()
        text = '{0} says: {1}'.format(self.name, cc_tmp.content())
        return text

class ContentContainer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.method_counter()
    def content(self):
        return 'Content from ContentContainer'
    def method_counter(self):
        pass

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    '''No mocking'''
    def test_printer_01(self):
        cc = ContentContainer()
        sut = Printer('P01', cc)
        result = sut.show_content()
        expected_result = 'P01 says: Content from ContentContainer'
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_result, 
                         msg = '\nRetrieved:\n{0} \nExpected:\n{1}'.format(result, expected_result))
        result = sut.retrieve_and_show_content()
        expected_result = 'P01 says: Content from ContentContainer'
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_result, 
                         msg = '\nRetrieved:\n{0} \nExpected:\n{1}'.format(result, expected_result))

    '''Create a mock object, which is the input of the method under test'''
    def test_printer_02(self):
        mock_cc = Mock()
        mock_cc.content.return_value = 'Mocked content'
        sut = Printer('P02', mock_cc)
        result = sut.show_content()
        expected_result = 'P02 says: Mocked content'
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_result, 
                         msg = '\nRetrieved:\n{0} \nExpected:\n{1}'.format(result, expected_result))
        self.assertFalse(mock_cc.method_counter.called, 'Method method_counter shall not be called')

    '''Create a mock class, which is instantiated inside the method under test'''
    @patch('TestMockClass.ContentContainer')
    def test_printer_03(self, mock_cc):
        mock_cc.content.return_value = 'Mocked content'
        sut = Printer('P03', mock_cc)
        result = sut.retrieve_and_show_content()
        expected_result = 'P03 says: Mocked content'
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_result, 
                         msg = '\nRetrieved:\n{0} \nExpected:\n{1}'.format(result, expected_result))
        self.assertFalse(mock_cc.method_counter.called, 'Method method_counter shall not be called')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When this unittest is run, the output is:

```
AssertionError: 
Retrieved:
P03 says: Content from ContentContainer 
Expected:
P03 says: Mocked content
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two things:

1. Because `ContentContainer` is now in the same file as the tests, you actually need to patch `__main__.ContentContainer`:

   ```
   @patch('__main__.ContentContainer')
   ```
2. Because `ContentContainer` is a class and you're calling `content` on an instance of that class, you actually wish to mock `content` on that instance, not on the class. You therefore need to do: `mock_cc.return_value.content.return_value = 'Mocked content'` (note the additional `.return_value` in there to make sure you're mocking the instance, not the class). This is because calling a class creates an instance. So, the instance is the return value of the call on the class.

The test should thus look like:

```
@patch('__main__.ContentContainer')
def test_printer_03(self, mock_cc):
    mock_cc.return_value.content.return_value = 'Mocked content'
    ...
```

Comment: Cool, from the docs - ```This means you access the “mock instance” by looking at the return value of the mocked class.```